# What is the best way of formatting a lot of html attributes in angular html code?

Tags: html, angularjs

Sometime some Angular directive needs a lot of arguments. In my current project I encounter a lot of different ways of formatting such code.

Which type of formatting should be used in Angular project?

## 1

```
<abc-table-widget aaa="aaa"
                  bbbb="bbbb"
                  widget="tableWidget"
                  ccc-id="{{ ccc.data.id }}"
                  ddd-id="{{ ddd.data.id }}"
                  eee-active="currentTab === TAB_EEE"
                  behavior="ACCORDION"
                  resource-type="{{ getResourceType() }}">
</abc-table-widget>
```

## 2

```
<abc-table-widget 
    aaa="aaa"
    bbbb="bbbb"
    widget="tableWidget"
    ccc-id="{{ ccc.data.id }}"
    ddd-id="{{ ddd.data.id }}"
    eee-active="currentTab === TAB_EEE"
    behavior="ACCORDION"
    resource-type="{{ getResourceType() }}">
</abc-table-widget>
```

## 3

```
<abc-table-widget aaa="aaa" bbbb="bbbb" widget="tableWidget" 
    ccc-id="{{ ccc.data.id }}" ddd-id="{{ ddd.data.id }}"
    eee-active="currentTab === TAB_EEE" behavior="ACCORDION" 
    resource-type="{{ getResourceType() }}"></abc-table-widget>
```

## 4

```
<abc-table-widget aaa="aaa" bbbb="bbbb" widget="tableWidget" ccc-id="{{ ccc.data.id }}" ddd-id="{{ ddd.data.id }}" eee-active="currentTab === TAB_EEE" behavior="ACCORDION" resource-type="{{ getResourceType() }}"> </abc-table-widget>
```

Comment: That is primarily opinion based, but when you have questions like that go for code readability and maintainability, the easier to read for you the better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's basically a question of your own preferences. To be honest I would suggest you to forget about your 3rd and 4th example very quickly.

I think your 2nd solution is the way to do it. Making so many tabs for your arguments like in example 1 seems to be quite a bit overhead.

If you take a look at the HTML-Coding-Guidelines from w3schools, you can see that they do the same.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp

EDIT: Nothing like that is on w3schools.com but here: http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24011&seqNum=3

Comment: "If you take a look at the HTML-Coding-Guidelines from w3schools, you can see that they do the same." - I don't see examples with many attributes splitted into multiple lines.

Comment: You're right, take a look here: http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24011&seqNum=3